# Strange results when applying Wilcoxon test in R

Tags: r, sample, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, independence

I am interested in whether the mean of one sample is statistically greater than the mean of the other one. The samples are not independent in that if the ith observation in sample A is positive, than the ith observation in sample B is "-1" and vice versa.

To answer this question I used Wilcoxon test in r and performed the analysis for different samples. In each pair of samples I have larger mean for the first sample than for the second one. However, the test sometimes shows p-value of one, whereas the same test with alternative = "less" rejects the null hypothesis. I find this counterintuitive. Is there smth wrong?

The files to run the code are here:

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/747619/doc1.csv

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/747620/doc2.csv

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/747621/doc3.csv

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/747622/doc4.csv .

And the code is below:

```
aa <- read.csv("doc1.csv")
bb <- read.csv("doc2.csv")
cc <- read.csv("doc3.csv")
dd <- read.csv("doc4.csv")

aa1 <- aa[,2]
aa2 <- aa[,3]
bb1 <- bb[,2]
bb2 <- bb[,3]
cc1 <- cc[,2]
cc2 <- cc[,3]
dd1 <- dd[,2]
dd2 <- dd[,3]

mean(aa1)
mean(aa2)
mean(bb1)
mean(bb2)
mean(cc1)
mean(cc2)
mean(dd1)
mean(dd2)

wilcox.test(aa1,aa2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(bb1,bb2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(cc1,cc2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(dd1,dd2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)

wilcox.test(aa1,aa2, alternative = "l", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(bb1,bb2, alternative = "l", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(cc1,cc2, alternative = "l", paired = TRUE)
wilcox.test(dd1,dd2, alternative = "l", paired = TRUE)
```

Comment: Given your condition: `The samples are not independent in that if the ith observation in sample A is positive, than the ith observation in sample B is "-1" and vice versa.`, I don't know how you would use a (paired) Wilcoxon test.  I suspect you would want to change the process that is arranging the data in this way...  Also, the Wilcoxon signed rank test may not be a test of means in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Which test would you then recommend for comparing the means in my case?

Comment: I have no idea.  I can't imagine what you'd be trying to find out from such a data set, or how such a data set would come to be... I would reassess how this data is being generated: What does a negative 1 mean?  Could it be some other value?  Can you discard all negative 1's?

Comment: Thanks again! The data cannot be reassessed or modified. These numbers are simply the returns to betting strategies for two-outcomes games: in every game if one result happens, then you loose the bet from the other outcome (that's how -1's come into play) and the bet on the realized outcome delivers a positive value.

Comment: The way the data are arranged doesn't make any sense because you are using one variable to hold two types of data: if the bet was lost, and the return value (?).  You might want to look at these separately.  1) which stategy was more likely to win, and 2) which strategy had the higher return.

Comment: In these datasets I simulate two strategies: one is betting on favorites and the other one is betting on outsiders. The question is whether the mean returns of these two strategies are statistically different. The returns from the strategies are paired by games.

Comment: Does A represent only the return?  Or does it sometimes represent the return, and other times represent this flag, -1, which is not a return?

Comment: All the observations are always returns.

Comment: Okay. I think your data are clear to me now.  Essentially, the bet is always $1, so a loss is always -1, but a win can be different amounts, which are recorded as positive.

Comment: Exactly! In fact these numbers are relative returns, i.e. they are independent of the bet size (assuming the bet size is identical for two strategies). For example, -1 means the return of -100% (full loss of the invested capital) and 0.62 means the return of 62% on the invested amount (bet size). But you are right, the example with a bet of size 1 is just another way to understand the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes" in the post?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem.  Probably someone will have a better solution, but I will keep with the paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test for now.  ***Edit: I don't really like using the Wilcoxon in this context. See ending comments.***

I think the first thing to realize is that the Wilcoxon test isn't a test of means, so it's possible that the Wilcoxon test is calling the group with the lower mean, "larger".

With the distributions of data, I don't know if there is a test of means that will be satisfactory.

That being said, the mean is probably the best estimator of the expected return, so that may be what you want to go with in the end.

```
### Install the packages
if(!require(lattice)){install.packages("lattice")}

### Read in the data
aa <- read.csv("C:/Users/Salma/Desktop/doc1.csv")
aa1 <- aa[,2]
aa2 <- aa[,3]

### Make it a data frame for convenience
Return = c(aa1, aa2)
Strategy = c(rep("Strategy1", length(aa1)), rep("Strategy2", length(aa2)))
Data = data.frame(Strategy, Return)
```

Looking at the histograms of the data will give of some sense of what we're dealing with.

It's clear that Strategy2 has a higher percentage of losses (about 60%), but that when it wins, its winnings tend to be higher than those of Strategy1.

```
library(lattice)

histogram(~ Return | Strategy,
          data=Data,
          layout=c(1,2))
```

[image]

But the paired test doesn't look at these independent distributions.  What it does is take the difference between the two paired observations, and then see if these differences are statistically different from zero.

For intuition here, imagine balancing the histogram of differences on a fulcrum at zero.  Which way does it tip?  (But the test uses ranks at this point, so the white space may matter less to the test than in the plot.) The way I did the math, if it tips right (positive), that would mean aa2 (Strategy2) is "larger".

```
Difference = aa2 - aa1   #### Positive means aa2 is higher

hist(Difference, col="darkgray")
```

[image]

The Wilcoxon paired test comes out significant.  But with a large sample size, there aren't too many conclusions we can draw from the *p*-value.

(I'm also worried about how you would interpret the conclusion given the distribution here.  We can conclude that the ranks are not symmetric around zero, but how to explain why?...)

```
wilcox.test(aa1,aa2, paired = TRUE)

   ### Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
   ###
   ### V = 242560, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

In order to determine the direction of the weight of the ranks, probably the easiest way is to look at the median of the difference.  I'm not sure if this is fool-proof for this test.

```
median(Difference)

   ### [1] -1.5
```

This suggests that aa1 (Strategy1) is "larger".

---

Finally, how do we square this with using the *alternative* option in the function? I don't know.  It's not making sense to me.

```
Big   = c(5,6,7,8,9,10)
Small = c(1,3,2,4,3,5)

wilcox.test(Big,Small, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)

   ### Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
   ### V = 21, p-value = 0.01751
   ### alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0

wilcox.test(aa1,aa2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)

   ### Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
   ### V = 242560, p-value = 1
   ### alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

---

Overall, I'm not very happy with this approach.  I think if we're looking at expected return, we should be looking at the mean value.  The ranks based approach, I think, is too likely to discount rarer and higher returns.

---

***Edit:*** I'll offer one other approach.

It might be possible to use a confidence interval for the mean of the differences, or alternatively for the mean of the returns for each strategy.

Here, I'll just get the 95% confidence intervals for the mean of the differences.  The mean of the differences is about -0.05, suggesting aa1 (Strategy1) is larger, the way I did the math above.  The confidence intervals for the mean of the difference contain zero, suggesting this mean is not statistically different from zero.  I'm not sure about this approach for data with a distribution as shown above.

```
if(!require(boot)){install.packages("boot")}

library(boot)

Mboot = boot(Difference,
             function(x,i) mean(x[i]),
             R=10000)

mean(Mboot$t[,1])

   ### [1] -0.04991604

hist(Mboot$t[,1], col="darkgray")

boot.ci(Mboot,
        conf = 0.95,
        type = c("norm", "basic" ,"perc", "bca")
        )

   ### Intervals : 
   ### Level      Normal              Basic         
   ### 95%   (-0.1605,  0.0631 )   (-0.1590,  0.0637 )  
   ###
   ### Level     Percentile            BCa          
   ### 95%   (-0.1623,  0.0604 )   (-0.1627,  0.0603 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! I posted this question quite a few days ago, so since then I also reconsidered the original idea of using Wilcoxon test. And, I also does not like it at all. In fact this is one of the ways I saw in academic literature, dealing with the problem of different returns from betting on favorites and outsiders, so called favorite-longshot bias. Another approach is to perform no statistical tests at all, but simply compare the actual means.

Comment: What I tried as a potentially better approach is bootstrapping using wBoot package in R. For example, with this functions:
boot.paired.bca(x, y, null.hyp = 0, alternative = "greater")
boot.paired.bca(x, y, null.hyp = 0)

boot.paired.per(x, y, null.hyp = 0, alternative = "greater", R = 100000)
boot.paired.per(x, y, null.hyp = 0)
However, I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: No problem.  I'm really not sure what is a good approach here.  Interesting, tho. 
 I added some to my answer using bootstrapped confidence intervals for the mean of the differences.  Maybe your functions do a similar thing in a more legitimate manner.

Comment: Thanks! Actually the functions I used claim to test paired-samples hypothesis for the difference between two population means and build confidence intervals. They also provide p-values. But, I am still a bit skeptical about the overall approach and its implementation.